# Не удалось найти выполняемый проект

Tags: c#

При запуске проекта через "dotnet run" возникла проблема "Не удалось найти выполняемый проект. Убедитесь в том, что проект существует в C:\Users\Admin\Desktop, или передайте путь к проекту с помощью --project."
Пробовал перемещать проект из папки в папку, но всё бессмысленно.

[image: код]

Я только начинаю учить С# и с таким никогда не сталкивался

Comment: Кажется вы что-то поломали в проекте, код здесь не при чем. Пересоздайте проект через dotnet new. И заведите на диске отдельную папку для проектов

Comment: _не вставляйте здесь код и другую текстовую информацию картинками, текст надо вставлять текстом_

Comment: Как то я сильно сомневаюсь, что проект находится  на рабочем столе. Откуда вообще эта команда выполняется, где была запущена командная строка? Даже если каталог решения на рабочем столе, следует зайти в него, а если в каталоге несколько под-проектов, либо установить путь, либо зайти в подкаталог исполняемого проекта.